# Mirror reordering in Thrust

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

I'm using thrust vector.

I'm looking for an elegant method for reordering a thrust device vector using a "mirror" ordering,   (example given, couldn't find any function for that in Thrust )

For instance, Let's say my vector contain  a struct, each struct contains several numbers. 
my vector looks like the following

```
[1,2]   [5,4]    [-2,5]     [6,1]     [2,6]
```

after mirror reordering operation I'd like to receive the following vector 
(the 1st element switched with  the n-th element) 
(the i  element switched with  the n-i element, etc )

```
[2,6]   [6,1]    [-2,5]    [5,4]    [1,2]
```

Is there any elegant way doing so in Thrust ?

BTW, I was thinking about giving each struct a unique ID number and sort according to that number, that way I could "mirror " reorder the vector using sorting.

Comment: PLease don't put tags in the title of you question. It isn't necessary. [SO] has tags, repeating them in the title isn't just unnecessary, it is unwanted.

Comment: Isn't this just `thrust::reverse`?

Comment: @Jared Hoberock , you are right, it's simple as reverse, write an answer and I'll set your answer as right answer.http://thrust.github.io/doc/namespacethrust.html#a076e8291a8d5a1748cc4623b8c758c93

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `thrust::reverse`:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reverse.h>
#include <thrust/pair.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  thrust::device_vector<thrust::pair<int,int> > vec;

  vec.push_back(thrust::make_pair( 1,2));
  vec.push_back(thrust::make_pair( 5,4));
  vec.push_back(thrust::make_pair(-2,5));
  vec.push_back(thrust::make_pair( 6,1));
  vec.push_back(thrust::make_pair( 2,6));

  std::cout << "input: " << std::endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
  {
    thrust::pair<int,int> x = vec[i];
    std::cout << " [" << x.first << ", " << x.second << "]";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  thrust::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end());

  std::cout << "output: " << std::endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
  {
    thrust::pair<int,int> x = vec[i];
    std::cout << " [" << x.first << ", " << x.second << "]";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
$ nvcc reverse.cu -run
input: 
 [1, 2] [5, 4] [-2, 5] [6, 1] [2, 6]
output: 
 [2, 6] [6, 1] [-2, 5] [5, 4] [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

[thrust::gather](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__gathering.html) allows for arbitrary copying of source vector elements to destination vector  elements according to a map (vector).

Here's a worked example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/gather.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

#define DSIZE 7

struct myStruct {
  int x;
  int y;
};

int main(){

  // create input data
  thrust::host_vector<myStruct> h(DSIZE);
  for (int i=0; i< DSIZE; i++){
    h[i].x = 2*i;
    h[i].y = (2*i)+1;
    }

  // create map
  thrust::device_vector<int> map(DSIZE);
  thrust::sequence(map.begin(), map.end(), DSIZE-1, -1);

  //move to device
  thrust::device_vector<myStruct> d = h;
  thrust::device_vector<myStruct> d_result(DSIZE);

  thrust::gather(map.begin(), map.end(), d.begin(), d_result.begin());

  //move to host
  thrust::host_vector<myStruct> h_result = d_result;

  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++){
    printf("result[%d].x = %d, result[%d].y = %d\n", i, h_result[i].x, i, h_result[i].y);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the suggestion from Jared Hoberock is simpler.